# How do you save the value of a randomly generated number for recalling in a different function?

Tags: javascript, variables, random, save

How do you save the output of a random number generator function to be recalled in a different function?

For example, in the code below, I would be using the `function randNum()` to roll the dice and `return` the value of `w` to the `saveDiceNumber()` function as a variable.

Then I would save the first value received from the `randNum()` function into the new variable `x` located in the `saveDiceNumber()` function. Then I would like to repeat the process for variables `y` and `z`, without losing the newly created value of `x`.

So in essence, I would like to create a single function that uses the same random number generator to create 3 different variables and then recall the value of those variables without having to re-generate/re-roll random numbers.

---

The random number generator function:

```
function randNum(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*6); 
}
```

Function where RNG output should be saved:

```
function saveDiceNumber(){
    var w = randNum(); //roll the dice for the first permanent value

    var x = randNum(); //second output of dice
    var y = randNum(); //third output of dice
    var z = randNum(); //forth output of dice

    pickFruit(x);
    }
```

Where the output of `saveDiceNumber()` will be used:

```
   function pickFruit(letter){

       switch(letter){
       case(1):
       console.log("Apples");
       break;
       case(2):
       console.log("Pears");
       break;
       case(3):
       console.log("Bananas");
       break;
       case(4):
       console.log("Mangos");
       break;
       case(5):
       console.log("Pineapples");
       break;
       case(6):
       console.log("Avacados");
       break;
}
```

Typing: `saveDiceNumber()` will console log different fruit every time, even though the function `pickFruit(x)` is the same.

I need the value of the variable `x` to permanently equal to `=` the value generated by one usage of the `randNum()` function.

So if I roll a 3, then `x` needs to be permanently equal to 3.

Comment: btw, what is the purpose of `Math.floor(6)`?

Comment: Yeah `Math.floor`-ing `6` it is unnecessary

Comment: where do you use `x`, ...`z`? do you need to know the last values? what about a stack

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Do you want `x`, `y`, `z` to have their own values generated from `randNum()` or do you want them all to have the save values as each other. Because the code you provided makes it so `x`, `y`, `z` have the same values as each other

Comment: @Nick Parsons - I would like `x` , `y` , `z` to have their own values generated from `randNum()`.

Comment: Then why not just `x = randNum(); y = randNum(); z = randNum();`

Comment: @Jonas W - You could do that but the `saveDiceNumber()` function will give `x, y, z` a new value every time the `saveDiceNumber()` function is called. What i'm trying to do is have the dice roll once `randNum()` and permanently save the values for `x, y, z`.

Comment: ... and isnt that what your code is doing?!

Comment: @Jonas W. - It is, but only temporarily. For example, i've edited the code to have a function where the variables are used. If I was to call the function `saveDiceNumber()` and then the RNG`randNum()` would roll a 3 to which the same function `saveDiceNumber()` would call the function `pickFruit(letter)` to consistently bring back fruit `case(3)` when ever the `saveDiceNumber()` function is called.

Thereby permanently saving the value 3 into `var x` via the `randNum()` function.

Comment: (no, i dont understand the edit.) do you need the three variables only inside of `saveDiceNumber`? why is `letter` a number?

Comment: @Nina Scholz - I edited the original post again, please refer for more understanding.

I need the variables within the `saveDiceNumber()` function to contain separate and permanent values for the letters `w, x, y ,z` which are derived from the dice roll `randNum()` function. 

`letter` is a number because it recalls the correct `case` from the value given to the variable letters `x, y, z` from the randomly generate number `randNum()` function.

Comment: maybe you are looking for global variables.

Comment: @Nina Scholz - Sadly, no because it will still give me a random number each time the variable is called.

Comment: @Jonas W. Could you please unmark this question as it is not a duplicate? Thank you.

Comment: @Jonas W - I understand that but even though it may not be clear for you, it may be clear for someone else. I'm willing to respond to any questions about what is being said to help others come to an understanding, just as I did with your questions.

Could you please let others try to answer it before closing it?

Thank you.

Comment: at which time do you like to set `y and `z` to the random value? what should happen with them (after setting)?

Comment: @NinaScholz you are an absolute legend! The fix i needed was to create 2  more random number generators and make the `w, x, y, z` into global variables (like you mentioned before) - Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this question has been very confusing to understand. I have managed to fix what I needed by doing the following:

```
//global variables
        var x = randNum1();
        var y = randNum2();
        var z = randNum3();

function randNum1(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*6); 
}

function randNum2(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*6); 
}

function randNum3(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*6); 
}

pickFruit(x);
pickFruit(y);
pickFruit(z);
```